# Spring Boot JPA implementation for the different environments / DB platforms

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

For the `stage`/`prod` environment I have implemented a bunch of CRUD interfaces, by calling MSSQL stored procedures in this way::

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends LoadableRepository<SubCategory, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "EXEC cls.Category", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SubCategory> findAll();

    ...
}
```

That works fine. 
But what if I want to to run my application using embedded DB for the `dev` environment? Stored procedures is a restriction. So I have no option to use basic `SELECT` queries.

Unfortunately nor H2 either HSQL engines does not support MSSQL stored procedures syntax.

Is it possible (how is better) to support both environments without changing Spring Boot application logic too much? 
I mean having real `stage` MSSQL DB and some kind of emulated DB on a `dev` environment without setting `@ConditionalBeans` for each environment?

Comment: If your code uses database specific features you are no longer independent and loose the ability to switch the database product.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes, that's clear. The question is how is better to prevent it?

Comment: Don't use stored procedures when using JPA. Because stored procedures may contain business logic and you will distribute the logic when using stored procedures.